# Compare multiple columns in a dataframe and generate a similarity matrix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose that I have a dataframe consisting of four columns *Col1, Col2, Col3 and Col4*.
Each column has 100 entries (assume timestamp), thus the overall shape of the dataframe is (100,4). 
For a given particular timestamp, these columns have similar values, thus making their overall variation with time very similar. 
Now, I would like to generate a 4x4 matrix the values in which provide the *similarity* among these columns within a scale of [0, 1], with 1 telling you that data is exactly same (sitting along the diagonal).

Can anyone please help me with a way to do it ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
Fs = 100
f = 5
sample = 100
x = np.arange(sample)
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * x / Fs)
y1 = np.sin(3 * np.pi * f * x / Fs)
y2 = np.sin(4 * np.pi * f * x / Fs)
y3 = np.sin(5 * np.pi * f * x / Fs)
data=pd.DataFrame({"c":y,"c1":y1,"c2":y2,"c3":y3})
data.cov()
```

You can use data.cov()

Reference:-

1. [data.cov()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cov.html)